# Function Pointer WINAPI

Tags: c, pointers

I need help with the code below.

```
typedef TP_StatusType ( WINAPI * TP_UserSelectPathType )( TP_InterfaceType* anInterface, UINT32* aReturnPathId, TP_Path* aReturnPath );
extern TP_UserSelectPathType TP_UserSelectPath;

locRouterDll = LoadLibraryA( aDllFileName );
TP_UserSelectPath = (TP_UserSelectPathType)GetProcAddress( locRouterDll, "TP_UserSelectPath" );

TP_StatusType eStatus;
eStatus = TP_UserSelectPath( &eInterface, &lPathId, &xPathHandle );
```

Which function is called in the last line?

Comment: Perhaps I misunderstood the question; in the last line, the function `TP_UserSelectPath` is called, which is assigned to some external code in the first line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Which function is called in the last line?

Well, `TP_UserSelectPath` is a function pointer variable that is assigned the function pointer returned by the call to `GetProcAddress`. So

```
TP_UserSelectPath(...)
```

calls the function named `TP_UserSelectPath` that is exported by the module `locRouterDll`. This is a function that is external to your code. The function is implemented in the module `locRouterDll` which was loaded into your process dynamically at runtime by the call to `LoadLibraryA`.

If this is all brand new to you then you should start by reading the [Dynamic-Link Libraries topic on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/ms682589.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

`TP_UserSelectPath` is called because you are assigning the return value of `TP_UserSelectPath` with the following parameters   `&eInterface, &lPathId, &xPathHandle` to `eStatus`